# How to align flexbox columns left and right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

With typical CSS I could float one of two columns left and another right with some gutter space in-between. How would I do that with flexbox?

http://jsfiddle.net/1sp9jd32/

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
#a {
  width: 20%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
#b {
  width: 20%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">
    a
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    b
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 405, accepted):

You could add `justify-content: space-between` to the parent element. In doing so, the children flexbox items will be aligned to opposite sides with space between them.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLh0foy/)

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#a {
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

#b {
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">
        a
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        b
    </div>
</div>
```

---

You could also add `margin-left: auto` to the second element in order to align it to the right.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3t2uj4hz/)

```
#b {
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    display: flex;
}

#a {
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#b {
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">
        a
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        b
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, could you please explain how the element gets correctly right aligned by using `margin-left: auto` here?

Comment: @hulkinBrain, here's the explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Comment: NOTE: `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` trick is not IE11 compatible, for those who still have to support it.

Answer (score 50):

I came up with 4 methods to achieve the results. Here is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/geniuscarrier/jeLfc7wt/2/)

Method 1:

```
#a {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Method 2:

```
#a {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Method 3:

```
#b {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Method 4:

```
#container {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Method 5: insert an extra empty element with `flex:1;` wherever you want the extra space to be :)

Comment: This would be the best, most complete answer if you embedded the code snippet instead of linking to jsfiddle.

Comment: Method 1 and 3 is not compatible with IE 11!

Comment: Note: method #2 - I think doesn't right align #b, rather it let's #a grow, so that doesn't answer the question - "with gutter space between".

Answer (score 19):

Another option is to add another tag with `flex: auto` style in between your tags that you want to fill in the remaining space.

https://jsfiddle.net/tsey5qu4/

The HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="fill-remaining-space"></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.fill-remaining-space {
  flex: auto;
}
```

This is equivalent to flex: 1 1 auto, which absorbs any extra space along the main axis.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways but simplest would be to use the space-between see the example at the end

```
#container {    
    border: solid 1px #000;
    display: flex;    
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
}

.item {
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[see the example](http://jsfiddle.net/xfr98e0q/2/)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jost's answer, if you need to align it vertically too, use `align-items: center;` if needed.

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```