# How to add Component ranged right to Navbar in AppLayout?

Tags: java, html, css, vaadin, vaadin14

My `MainView` `extends` of an `AppLayout`. 
I want to fill the Navbar with a logo on the left side of it and the user id on the right side of the Navbar. 
Unfortunately everything I tried ends with both Components bound to the left side.

Navbar goal:

> | Image
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  UserID |

Example code (same outcome with Vaadin 14 Image and a String):

```
public class MainView extends AppLayout
...

private void setupNavigationBar() {
    Div a = new Div();
    a.setText("Foo");
    a.getStyle().set("flex-flow", "flex-start");

    Div b = new Div();
    b.setText("Bar");
    b.getStyle().set("flex-flow", "flex-end");
    addToNavbar(a, b);
}
```

Navbar outcome:

> | FooBar
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |

What is the issue here? Why does the `flex-flow` not work? I already tried to wrap it in a `HorizontalLayout` which also does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a similar case here [How to align flexbox columns left and right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922126/how-to-align-flexbox-columns-left-and-right)and solution seems to work for me like you describe:

```
@Route("custom-appLayout")
public class CustomAppLayout extends AppLayout {
    public CustomAppLayout(){
            Image img = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/GPpnszs.png", "Vaadin Logo");
            img.setHeight("44px");
            addToNavbar(new DrawerToggle(), img);
            Tabs tabs = new Tabs(new Tab("Home"), new Tab("About"));
            tabs.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.VERTICAL);
            addToDrawer(tabs);
            addToNavbar(img);

            Div b = new Div();
            b.setText("Bar");
            b.getStyle().set("margin-left", "auto");
            b.getStyle().set("padding", "15px");
            addToNavbar(b);
    }
}
```

I've added a `padding`, since otherwise `Bar` is too close to the end, but you could set any value you want there. 
And this is how it looks like:
[image]

Links I've used:

- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) This is my favorite article about flexbox . I'm pretty much always looking for it, when want to check something : )
- [AppLayout official docs](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-app-layout/). A stub snippet code is taken from there

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification and your time! I miss used the flex-flow I guess.